# Change options and value at the same time

Tags: vue.js

I have a problem when I try to change the options of my select and its value at the same time. If I use `v-model`, it works properly but if I use `v-bind:value` + `v-on:change`, it will not work.

Here is a js fiddle that will illustrate the problem : https://jsfiddle.net/2vcer6dz/18/

The first time you click on the button "change", only the first select value will be 3. If you reclick they all become 3.

**Html**

```
<div id="app">
  <select v-model="value">
    <option v-for="item in options" :key="item.Value" :value="item.Value">{{item.Text}}</option>
  </select>
  <select :value="value" v-on:change="value = $event.target.value">
    <option v-for="item in options" :key="item.Value" :value="item.Value">{{item.Text}}</option>
  </select>
  <select-option v-model="value" :options="options"></select-option>
  <br />
  <input type="button" value="change" v-on:click="change" />
</div>

<template id="template-select-option">
    <select :value="value" v-on:change="update($event.target.value)">
        <option v-for="item in options" :key="item.Value" :value="item.Value">{{item.Text}}</option>
    </select>
</template>
```

**Javascript**

```
Vue.component('select-option', {
  template: '#template-select-option',
  props: ['value', 'options'],
  methods: {
    update: function (value) {
      this.$emit('input', value);
    }
  }
});

new Vue({
    el: '#app',
  data: {
    value: 1,
    options: [{Value:1, Text:1}, {Value:2, Text:2}]
  },
  methods: {
    change: function () {
      this.options = [{Value:1, Text:1}, {Value:2, Text:2}, {Value:3, Text:3}];
      this.value = 3;
    }
  }
});
```

**Expected result**

All selects should have the value "3" when you click on the button "change"

Comment: that is because v-models behave in the same way as :value="{expression}"

Comment: @samayo How does it explain the problem in the jsfiddle?

Comment: well what's your expected end result

Comment: @samayo That all the selects have the value "3" when you click on the button "change"

Comment: so you don't want the initial 3:1:1 but 3:3:3?

Comment: @samayo Yes, 3:1:1 is very strange since the value in my model is clearly "3" and not "1".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Changing the options and the value at the same time is confusing Vue. This is probably a minor bug in Vue. If you use `$nextTick` to push the value change off to the next update cycle, they all work.

```
change: function () {
  this.options = [{Value:1, Text:1}, {Value:2, Text:2}, {Value:3, Text:3}];
  this.$nextTick(() => {
      this.value = 3;
  });
}
```

Comment: Yeah, I thought so too ... it looked buggy as I tried to solve the issue

Comment: Thx, that's a nice trick to use $nextTick. I found a link to a github issue with the same problem. See my answer below

Answer (score 0):

It seems that this is a [known bug](https://github.com/vuejs/vue/issues/4810) which was closed because a workaround was found.

The workaround is to declare another property and cast v-model on it. This solutions is easier to implement inside a component.

https://jsfiddle.net/6gbfhuhn/8/

**Html**

```
<template id="template-select-option">
    <select v-model="innerValue">
        <option v-for="item in options" :key="item.Value" :value="item.Value">{{item.Text}}</option>
    </select>
</template>
```

**Javascript**

```
Vue.component('select-option', {
  template: '#template-select-option',
  props: ['value', 'options'],
  computed: {
    innerValue: {
      get: function() { return this.value; },
      set: function(newValue) { this.$emit('input', newValue); }
    }
  }
});
```

Note: In the github thread, it is suggested to use a computed property instead, but if you use a computed property, vue will throw warning every time you change the value in your dropdown because computed property don't have setter.

Comment: You can make a computed with a setter. It's a fairly elegant solution. https://jsfiddle.net/6gbfhuhn/11/